# TweetSharp text truncated

Tags: c#, tweets, tweetsharp

im trying to use tweetsharp to search some particular tweets. My code is working well except it will retrieve truncated text.

It will be like:[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lULni.png)

Here is my code:

```
public List<Tweets> serarch()
        {
            List<Tweets> tlist = new List<Tweets>();
            var service = new TwitterService("ck", "cs");



            service.AuthenticateWith("tk", "ts");

            var options = new SearchOptions { Q = "#sexualassault" };

            var tweets = service.Search(options);



            foreach (var tweet in tweets.Statuses)
            {


                if (tlist.Count == 50)
                    break;
                else
                {
                    tlist.Add(new Tweets {
                        Name = tweet.User.Name,
                        Text = tweet.Text

                });
                }
            }
            return tlist;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the results are truncated? This is Twitter we're talking about.

Comment: im sure about that, cuz when i go check the original tweet, some words are missing in my result.